# Повернуть объект не поворачивая сетку

Tags: c#, opengl

Поверх сетки рисуется объект. Как повернуть объект, не поворачивая сетку?

```
private void fieldGL_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (tabIndex == 1 && drawState == DrawState.Ok)
    {
        if (mbState == MouseButtonState.btnLeft)
        {
            double rotateX;

            Rotate rotate = new Rotate();

            gl.clear(Color.White);
            view.grid(size);        // Отрисовка сетки

            rotateX = pointStandart.X - e.X;

            Gl.glPushMatrix();

            /* Поворот и отрисовка объекта */
            rotate = view.rotateScene(rotateX, 0);
            Gl.glRotated(rotate.Angle, 0, 0, rotate.Y);

            DrawManager drawManager = new DrawManager();
            drawManager.draw(data, lineWidth);
            /* --- */

            Gl.glPopMatrix();

            fieldGL.Invalidate();

            pointStandart.X = e.X;
            pointStandart.Y = e.Y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это едва напоминает обычный OpenGL. Кто все эти л̶ю̶д̶и̶ объекты?

Comment: TaoFramework (c#). Там подписано, где рисуется сетка, а где само изображение. Проблема в том, что текущее положение glPushMatrix() и glPopMatrix() в коде не позволяет ничего повернуть

Comment: А что делает метод rotate = view.rotateScene(rotateX, 0);?

Comment: Если убрать glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix то у вас всё поварачивается?

Comment: rotate = view.rotateScene(rotateX, 0); определяет  параметры для glRotated(...); Если убрать, то поворачивает все, а нужно, чтобы сетка оставалась на месте, а все остальное поворачивалось.